# Store developer-defined build parameters in Visual Studio user files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have different dev environments between developers here. When I build, I want my compiled files to be copied to a bin folder located in `C:\Web\bin\`. Another developer may want those files dropped in `C:\Web_2011\bin\`.

Using Visual Studio 2010, the way we work this now is to run a BAT file with the directories defined as parameters that need to be changed if pulling from another developer's branch.

Is it possible to store a solution-wide parameter, (in a .user or .suo file maybe,) to define where a developer wants to drop his builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it through the project file (.vcxproj for C++ project for example).
The simplest solution would be to add a Custom Build Step that runs some batch file. This batch file could check the current user name and copy the files based on that.
(An even simpler solution would be to run a user specific batch file from his local disk)

If you really want the fully fledged solution that will allow you to save this data to the user file, you can do it by editing the project file and adding a PropertyPageSchema element that extends VS property pages with another parameter (your destination directory). You can define the Persistence attribute of DataSource element as "UserFile" and the data will be saved on your .user file. You will need to add some target that actually uses this data (copies files to the directory specified).
For more information, read about [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [PropertyPageSchema](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/06/18/platform-extensibility-part-2.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think to pull the username in the BAT file. That'll work for our needs, no problem.